Using XML Layout with Empty Activity in Android Studio
I've created a new Android project using the "Empty Activity" template, which I understand is typically used for Jetpack Compose UI development. However, I've noticed that my friend has successfully used XML layout files with an Empty Activity and Java code in their project.
This is link to GitHub that my friend's app GitHub
Is it possible to use XML layouts with an Empty Activity? If so, what are the implications and potential drawbacks compared to using the "Empty Views Activity" template? Are there any specific configurations or workarounds required to make this approach work?
I'm curious about the advantages and disadvantages of using XML with an Empty Activity versus the traditional approach. Any insights or experiences would be greatly appreciated.

Using XML or Jetpack Compose depends on your use case. Most of the tooling is well supported with Jetpack Compose since it's a new framework and helps you code your UI faster.
It's the same debate whether Java should be used over Kotlin. Ideally no, but if you still have some valid reason then go ahead
Either way, your app will work fine, and can be released on the Play Store
Advantages of using XML are as follows

Since it's been there for a long time, it can solve some complicated cases like nested scrolling easily, which Compose is bad at
Lots of tutorials and guides are available for XML, since majority apps are migrating to Compose, or are already working in XML
Resource Qualifiers and Localization are better supported in XML

Disadvantages

XML is a different language from Java or Kotlin, and is not very developer friendly
Building UI using Compose is easier due to using declarative programming, and results in faster coding

